# Compile Error in using /usr/include/net/if.h

Tags: macos, compilation, network-programming, libpcap, network-security

I'm trying to compile existing source code for a network sniffer on my Mac Lion. I installed libpcap. The source includes a header file /usr/include/net/if.h, which is throwing compilation errors as shown below.

```
Floyd:~ Shastry$ gcc -o arplisten arplisten.c -lpcap
In file included from arplisten.c:4:
/usr/include/net/if.h:265: error: field ‘ifru_addr’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/net/if.h:266: error: field ‘ifru_dstaddr’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/net/if.h:267: error: field ‘ifru_broadaddr’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/net/if.h:308: error: field ‘ifra_addr’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/net/if.h:309: error: field ‘ifra_broadaddr’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/net/if.h:310: error: field ‘ifra_mask’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/net/if.h:393: error: field ‘addr’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/net/if.h:394: error: field ‘dstaddr’ has incomplete type
arplisten.c:6:24: error: netinet/if.h: No such file or directory
arplisten.c: In function ‘main’:
arplisten.c:139: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
Floyd:~ Shastry$
```

I did a lot of googling for help, in vain. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's the order in which files are included.  See this [page](http://mailman.verplant.org/pipermail/collectd/2007-April/000898.html), which I found via google.

Comment: worked after I included if.h after including everything else! Thanks a ton!